# Implementing a Remote Proxy

Tags: java, rest, design-patterns

I'm reading a book on design patterns and am trying to implement the proxy pattern, specifically a remote proxy in one of my applications.

I was thinking of using this pattern when querying a remote REST API, but I'm unsure if what I am thinking of satisfies the definition of a remote proxy.

The below is a simplified version of what I've got so far.

**MachineApiProxy** would be used by the application to query the remote API that sits on another machine.

```
// Interface
public interface MachineApi
{
    public Integer Infocon();

    public InetAddress Ip();
}


// Implements above interface
public class MachineApiProxy implements MachineApi
{
    public Integer Infocon()
    {
        // query remote REST API
    }

    public InetAddress Ip()
    {
        // query remote REST API
    }

}
```

Do you think this satisfies implmenting a remote proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The participants in [Proxy](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Proxy/) pattern are:

- Subject – define common interface for RealSubject and Proxy
- RealSubject – real object which Proxy presents
- Proxy – keep reference on a real subject, so he can act as surogate

So in your case RealSubject which queries remote API is missing. RealSubject should connect to remote endpoint, ...
MachineApi looks like Subject.
Inject RealSubject in MachineApiProxy.

Comment: I don't understand how I can apply this to calling a remote API. What is the difference between Subject and RealSubject? Subject just uses RealSubject to call the API, and anything within my app that needs to call the API goes through Subject?

Comment: Implement "call to remote API" in RealSubject, you can use more intuitive name like RemoteSubject or RemoteMachineApi. RealSubject implements Subject, but Proxy holds reference to RealSubject. With this approach Proxy is barrier between Client and RealSubject(a surogate), so Client is not aware who is RealSubject. Check this link https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-proxy, hope that explanation helps.

Comment: Proxy is heavily used inside SpringFramework for AOP, intercetors, etc